# SystemCall to process and show a table of PID's, names and their states

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

So i have an assignment that I am having some difficulty wrapping my head around.  The assignment is to create a system call called "mysyscall3" that takes no input and produces

```
./a.out
PID COMM    STATE
1   systemd INT
2   kthreadd    INT
3   rcu_gp  OTHER
4   rcu_par_gp  OTHER
6   kworker/0:0H    OTHER
7   kworker/u4:0    OTHER
8   mm_percpu_wq    OTHER
9   ksoftirqd/0 INT
10  rcu_sched   OTHER
11  migration/0 INT
13  cpuhp/0 INT
14  cpuhp/1 INT
15  migration/1 INT
16  ksoftirqd/1 INT
18  kworker/1:0H    OTHER
20  kdevtmpfs   INT
21  netns   OTHER
22  kauditd INT
24  khungtaskd  INT
25  oom_reaper  INT
26  writeback   OTHER
27  kcompactd0  INT
28  ksmd    INT
29  khugepaged  INT
49  cryptd  OTHER
126 kintegrityd OTHER
127 kblockd OTHER
128 blkcg_punt_bio  OTHER
129 tpm_dev_wq  OTHER
130 md  OTHER
131 edac-poller OTHER
132 watchdogd   INT
158 kswapd0 INT
161 kthrotld    OTHER
162 acpi_thermal_pm OTHER
163 kmpath_rdacd    OTHER
164 kaluad  OTHER
166 ipv6_addrconf   OTHER
226 zswap-shrink    OTHER
242 kworker/u5:0    OTHER
456 nvme-wq OTHER
461 nvme-reset-wq   OTHER
464 nvme-delete-wq  OTHER
484 ena OTHER
507 xfsalloc    OTHER
513 xfs_mru_cache   OTHER
517 xfs-buf/nvme0n1 OTHER
518 xfs-conv/nvme0n OTHER
519 xfs-cil/nvme0n1 OTHER
520 xfs-reclaim/nvm OTHER
521 xfs-eofblocks/n OTHER
522 xfs-log/nvme0n1 OTHER
523 xfsaild/nvme0n1 INT
524 kworker/0:1H    OTHER
609 systemd-journal INT
639 systemd-udevd   INT
657 auditd  INT
701 dbus-daemon INT
702 irqbalance  INT
705 rngd    INT
709 chronyd INT
710 polkitd INT
721 sssd    INT
746 kworker/1:1H    OTHER
756 sssd_be INT
765 sssd_nss    INT
775 systemd-logind  INT
858 NetworkManager  INT
867 tuned   INT
1010    systemd-resolve INT
1063    rsyslogd    INT
1072    sshd    INT
1074    agetty  INT
1075    crond   INT
1076    agetty  INT
1188    kworker/0:2 OTHER
1535    kworker/0:3 OTHER
1546    sshd    INT
1550    systemd INT
1554    (sd-pam)    INT
1560    sshd    INT
1561    bash    INT
1691    kworker/u4:1    OTHER
1734    kworker/1:1 OTHER
1746    kworker/1:2 OTHER
1748    a.out   RUNNING
86 PIDS 1 RUNNING 43 INT 0 UNINT 0 STOPPED 0 TRACED 42 OTHER
```

The following is the test code that will be used to test out our system call

```
    /* test.c 
 *
 * test syscall3 442
 *
 * Compile:
 *     gcc test.c
 * Run:
 *     ./a.out
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SYS_mysyscall3 442

/* test.c
 *
 * gcc test.c  # compile
 *
 * Use dmesg to verify mysyscall3 was received by the kernel, i.e.
 * 
 * dmesg | grep mysyscall3
 *
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SYS_mysyscall3 442

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int maxp;
    long ret;
    char *buf;

    buf = (char*) malloc(512*2048);
    if ( buf == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error malloc buf\n");
        return 1;
    }
  
    if (argc != 1) {
        printf("mysyscall3 requires no input.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ret = syscall(SYS_mysyscall3, buf);

    if ( ret ) { // non-zero return value is an error
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: mysyscall3 returned %ld.\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

And below is what i have so far in my /kernel/sys.c file

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE(mysyscall3) {
        struct task_struct *task;
        int numPid = 0;
        char *buf;
        buf = (char *)kmalloc(*buf,GFP_KERNEL);
        if (buf == NULL) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "mysyscall3 kmalloc\n");
                return -EFAULT;
        }

        for_each_process(task) {
                buf = ("%d\t%s\t%ld\n", task->pid,task->comm,task->state);
                numPid++;
        }

        pr_info("%d PIDS\n",numPid);
        return 0;
}
```

So i want to make sure of a few things... since in the test code (2nd snippet) my professor is passing the buf parameter to the system call would it be correct to assume that my actual definition should be SYSCALL_DEFINE1?

Also, i have made the appropriate changes to my systables_64 file to add the system call , and yet on a fresh kernel rebuild and restart if i run my test code nothing is printed to the screen.  Should i be using something like copy_to_user() , and if so, should i do that in the for_each_process(3rd code document).  I would like to just get something printed to my screen but thats where i keep getting stuck, maybe someone could point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`. BTW, in your system call implementation you create **local** variable `buf`. How do you expect a local variable to be propagated outside of the function or otherwise printed into the screen?

Comment: by using copy_to_user() to bring it to the userspace, is there another way ?

Comment: Yes, copiing into the user space area should be performed with `copy_to_user`. Note, that `for_each_process` should be used inside **RCU read section** (between `rcu_read_lock()` and `rcu_read_unlock()` functions calls). Operations like `copy_to_user`, which involves possible "sleeping", cannot be used under RCU read section, so you need to use `copy_to_user` **outside** of `for_each_process` iteration.

Comment: Note that the kernel code you show doesn't look like valid C. You should update your question.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Except the line `buf = ("%d\t%s\t%ld\n", task->pid,task->comm,task->state);` the kernel code seems to be perfectly valid. Construction `SYSCALL_DEFINE(mysyscall3)` actually defines a function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know. I was talking specifically about that line (which actually compiles but it's not what OP wants). Looks like a call to some kind of `sprintf` missing the function name.